# Автоматическое импортирование функций из глобального пространства

Tags: php, phpstorm

У меня есть огромный проект, решил обновиться до PHP 7.4, дело в том что PhpStorm не может автоматически импортировать все функции из глобального пространства (например use function strlen) которые используются в проекте. Вместо этого нужно бегать по проекту, убирать один символ вызова глобальной функции, писать его и нажимать энтер дабы глобальная функция импортировалась. Повторяю, в автоматическом режиме, чтобы все сделали за меня автоматически, ибо проект большой. Code -> Code cleanup не помогает.

Comment: не совсем понятно, а до обновления на 7,4 phpstorm автоматически импортировал функции из глобального постранства7

Comment: а зачем такое надо? с глобальным пространством и так всё работает. и это ни к чему

Comment: Нет, и никогда не импортировал.

Comment: Как это ни к чему?) Советую глянуть как это реализовано.

Comment: глянуть куда?..